# How to inspect child nodes in IDE debugger?

Tags: godot, debugging

Consider an enemy with this node hierarchy:

```
* KinematicBody2D (Enemey)
|- Sprite
|- CollisionShape
|- Area2D (StompDetector)
   |- CollisionShape2D
```

With signal from `StompDetector` to `Enemy`:

```
func _on_StompDetector_body_entered(body: Node) -> void:
    if body.global_position.y < $StompDetector.global_position.y:
        die() ## >> BREAKPOINT <<
```

That does not work as exepcted. How to inspect `$StompDetector` from the debugger at `BREAKPOINT`?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the debugger panel you will see the members variables of the current class/script and the local variables of the current function. The node you want is neither. Thus a solution is to store it in a variable.

However, if you want to access a different node while debugging there is another way…

While debugging, you can go to the Scene panel (on the top left of the editor by default), and you will see two tabs:

- **Local**: contains the scene tree for editing (which is what you have access normally).
- **Remote**: contains the current scene tree of the game that is running.

Use the Remote tab to get to nodes you want. When you select them, their current state will appear on the inspector panel (on the right of the editor by default).